# Is there any function which second derivative almost equivalent it major fuction

Tags: trigonometry

I know second derivative of sin cos sinh cosh functions are equivalent themselves with different sign. so my question is there any function similar or not?
Any help might be appreciated.

Comment: This is an off-topic. First it is on mathematics, rather than MMa, second it is based on a rough mathematical error.

Comment: thanks but what's your suggested site to ask my question??

Comment: It is Stack Exchange Mathematics

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) or migrated as it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e **it is not about Wolfram Mathematica programming**. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397). You can still [edit] your question to revert this decision.

Answer (score 1):

```
DSolve[x''[t] == -x[t], x[t], t]
```

> ```
> {{x[t] -> C[1] Cos[t] + C[2] Sin[t]}}
> ```

So `C[1] Cos[t] + C[2] Sin[t]` for any complex  `C[1]` , `C[2]` and `t`.

Comment: Also for complex t ;-)